# How to Limit the String in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

What i Need:

```
  * consider product name

   A.a

   B.b

  C.c

  D.d

  E.e

  F.f
```

on dump item array:

```
  array(7) 
   {["id"]=> int(42172) ["Company_Website"]=> string(19) "http://www.xkl.com/"   
  ["company_name"]=> string(3) "XKL" ["city_name"]=> string(8) "Kirkland"    
   ["country_name"]=> string(3) "USA" ["comp_img"]=> NULL ["Product_Name"]=> string(24)  
   ""Top End Transport System,Band Combiner Devices,Our Mid Level Transport System,The Introductory Transport System,In-Line Amplification Systems,Intelligent Ethernet Access System,Ethernet Access System,Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 05),Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 06),Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 03),Ethernet Aggregation Device"" 
    }
```

- I want to validate the string in such manner that it wouldn"t loop more then 5 product name.
- Then in my case f product would not we consider.

here is my tiwig file:

```
         <p class="prod">
            {% if item.Product_Name.text[:5]  %} 
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row flush nbdr pdt">
                    <div class="12u connect">
                    <p class="mr"><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> Connect</a> <span>Booth # 50</span></p>
                    </div>
        {% else if if item.Product_Name.text[:6]   %}
        <div class="row flush nbdr pdt">no data exist

                    </div>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [**`SLICE`**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

Comment: im new in twig please give some code snippet in such manner i want validatation for  more then  5 products

Comment: Posted as an answer with an example

Comment: does it work for string ex: a,b,c,d,e,f and restrict f

Comment: For string you can do so `{{ 'a,b,c,d,e'[:9] }}` 5 letters and 4 commas 5+4 =9

Comment: i need little help how to convert string into array in twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`SLICE`**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) over your product names array like if `item` contains products then you can do you as

```
{% for i in item|slice(0, 5) %}
    {{ i.Product_Name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will loop over only 5 records stored in `item` array()

Comment: Impossible to access an attribute ("Product_Name") on a integer variable ("42166")

Comment: array(7) { ["id"]=> int(42172) ["Company_Website"]=> string(19) "http://www.xkl.com/" ["company_name"]=> string(3) "XKL" ["city_name"]=> string(8) "Kirkland" ["country_name"]=> string(3) "USA" ["comp_img"]=> NULL ["Product_Name"]=> string(24) "Top End Transport System" }

Comment: what is in `item` and where you have product name stored ?

Comment: problem is slice is for array , item returning string i have to convert string=>array first then i could solve my problem.please tell me how t convert string to array in twig

Comment: @user3785613 can you ask new question regarding string to array and provide me the link of new question here i will try to answer that one thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262116/how-to-convert-string-to-array-in-twig

Answer (score 0):

'for' has [loop variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if loop.index <= 5 %}
        {{ item.Product_Name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unexpected token "operator" of value "="

Comment: If you want to check equal, you need to use '==' instead of '='.

Comment: i need little help how to convert string into array in twig

Comment: you can use filter 'split', for example: {% set foo = "one,two,three"|split(',') %}