# How To convert string to Array in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

what i Need:

string as follows:

```
  ["Product_Name"]=> string(362) "Top End Transport System,Band Combiner Devices,Our Mid Level Transport System,The Introductory Transport System,In-Line Amplification Systems,Intelligent Ethernet Access System,Ethernet Access System,Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 05),Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 06),Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 03),Ethernet Aggregation Device" }
```

- Im using php slice function in such manner so that i should validate string till 5 string.
- ex: Top End Transport System, ur Mid Level Transport System,The Introductory Transport System,In-Line Amplification Systems,Intelligent Ethernet Access System.
- i need till first five string.
- i have refer article http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html

here is  twig code:

```
            {% set foo = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
            {{ dump (foo) }}
           {% for i in item.Product_Name|slice(0, 5) %}
            {{ dump(i) }}
            {% endfor %}
```

- slice function is for array so , please tell how to convert product name to array in twig

Comment: i have t convert string in to array

Comment: Did u know a string is an array of chars?

Comment: Anyway, `slice` in twig also works with strings : The slice filter works as the array_slice PHP function for arrays and mb_substr for strings with a fallback to substr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop over your `foo` variable in order to print your products slice `foo` in order to get first five names `foo|slice(0, 5)`

```
{% set foo = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
{% for i in foo|slice(0, 5) %}
   {{ dump(i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can help in simple issue - i have to remove (,) from last array a,b,c,d,  so i have remove , after d .in my code - {{ dump(i) }}, so i have to remove last commas from there

Comment: @user3785613 try this `{{ dump(i[:-1]) }}`